# Cannot use LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_NOTIFICATIONS without LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_HOME

Tags: android, kotlin, kiosk-mode

I have made an Android based Kiosk application. I have successfully made that by creating Device Admin.

```
    val deviceAdmin = ComponentName(this, AppAdminReceiver::class.java)
            mDpm = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
            if (!mDpm!!.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_admin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (mDpm!!.isDeviceOwnerApp(packageName)) {
                mDpm!!.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, arrayOf(packageName))
           startLockTask()
             
    //            mDpm!!.clearDeviceOwnerApp(packageName);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_owner), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

this code disables bottom navigation bar with status bar(notification bar). Is there any way to enable status bar . I am developing solution for above Android 9